# Break out of while-read statement

Tags: bash

I'm working on a script to monitor log files from a couple of servers and email/txt alerts when certain keywords are shown.  All is working well to this point by using:

```
tail -n 0 -f "$MS01_LOG_FILE" "$MS02_LOG_FILE" | while IFS= read -r line; do
#do some fun things here
done
```

Trouble is, sometimes the server hangs up doesn't output to the log file for quite some time, and I would like to be notified of a stalled log. Of course, my script will just sit at the read-line waiting for input.  I need a sort of  timer that runs in the background I suppose that can break from the read-line.

Comment: You can try `... | while true; do IFS= read -r -t 42 line;  ... done`

Comment: @gollum, please post answers as answers (not as comments), so that they can be voted on and accepted

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

The following alternative should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

MS01_LOG_FILE=/var/log/dmesg
MS02_LOG_FILE=/var/log/syslog

TIMEOUT=10  # modify to your liking

tail -n 0 -f "$MS01_LOG_FILE" "$MS02_LOG_FILE" | while :
do
    IFS= read -t $TIMEOUT -r line
    # do your funny things here
done
```

**Details**

First quoting from `help read` (see [bash reference manual for the builtin command "read"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read))

> -t timeout
>   Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line of input (or a specified number of characters) is not read within
>   timeout seconds. timeout may be a decimal number with a fractional
>   portion following the decimal point. This option is only effective if
>   read is reading input from a terminal, pipe, or other special file; it
>   has no effect when reading from regular files. If read times out, read
>   saves any partial input read into the specified variable name. If
>   timeout is 0, read returns immediately, without trying to read and
>   data. The exit status is 0 if input is available on the specified file
>   descriptor, non-zero otherwise. The exit status is greater than 128 if
>   the timeout is exceeded.

Note that the exit status being greater than 128 for detecting a read timeout is not guaranteed between implementations (e.g. on my OS X's bash it is 1).

Now simply adding `-t $TIMEOUT` to your initial script provides only one part of the solution since the broken pipe won't be detected until anything gets emitted from the tail pipe.

Moving the `read` into a endless while loop solves that issue.

Depending on what you want to do instead of `# do your funny things here` you might now be confronted with the issue of escaping from that child process jail.

In that case check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558295/quit-from-pipe-in-bash

Comment: Also note that `bash`'s `read` like AT&T ksh's uses the `$TMOUT` variable (even one coming from the environment!) as default timeout.